# tsconfig noEmit must be true

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app and I also have some ts and tsx files. In my tsconfig file (see below) I set noEmit to false because js files need to be emitted. However, every time I start the server, noEmit is set to false with the following message:

```
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
   - compilerOptions.noEmit must be true
```

When noEmit is set to false, the js files that should be generated from my ts files, aren't generated, which means the app isn't updated. What causes this behaviour? Is there any way to avoid it? Or is the only option to make a seperate tsconfig for the folder with the ts files?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "ES2017"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why you think that `noEmit` should be false? I think that CRA uses ts-loader on the webpack side, therefore, there is no need for TS will transpile your code separtly.

Comment: But when noEmit is true, the app isn't updated when I change something in the typescript files.

Comment: How do you know that it is not gets updated? do you talk about ts files that related to the server by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

You need to override this compile option in your webpack.config-file, like this:

```
rules: [
     {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
           compilerOptions: {
              "noEmit": false
           }
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
```

Comment: I thought with CRA you cannot edit the webpack.config? Its driving me nuts

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Pull Request to try fix this issue for good here: [Link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/12868)

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the file change from react-script after the command execution.

In my case that's the test script that make me issue. So I added this to my package.json file :

```
  [...]
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "cp tsconfig.json tsconfig.json.save",
    "posttest": "mv tsconfig.json.save tsconfig.json",
    [...]
  }
```

***However, if your test fails, the file is not renamed to its original filename***

Answer (score 0):

If you use than VS Code, must create a copy of tsconfig.json file with name tsconfig-watch.json and change task.json file in .vscode folder like bellow code.

> in tsconfig-watch.json file, you must set "noEmit": false

```
    {
        "label": "tsc: watch",
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig-watch.json", //!important
        "option": "watch",
        "runOptions": {
            "runOn": "folderOpen"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc-watch"
        ]
    }
```